# UWP C# How would I Rearrange / Reorder a SQLite Database from a ListView

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, listview, uwp

Im currently having a problem with reordering my records / rows in my SQLite Database using the SQLite PCL, I have set up the ListView to be able to drag and reorder items but cant get my head around making them changes appear / save to the database. I haven't found a solid answer around the internet about changing the order of a SQLite Database Table using a ListView.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want users to be able to reorder the list in the way they like and store it that way in the database so that when the user reopens the UWP, the ListView gets ordered in the order they chose?

You can create a new property for eacht item called OrderIndex or something, and use that property when loading in the list for the user. You don't use the ID of the item, you use that property.

By default you could say they are the same, when a user puts one item above or beneath another, they can just swap their OrderIndex value.

I hope this idea inspires you :)